# На что ругается VS code

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скопировал код из видео,с int main все нормально, почему нельзя с void?
Точнее почему ругается.

Comment: функция `main` уже предварительно объявлена как `int main(int,char**)`, а вы написали эту функцию уже с отличающейся декларацией.

Answer (score 1):

main должен возвращать int. Так устроены операционные системы, если очень просто говорить, то любая программа должна "что-то" ответить. VS заблаговременно оберегает вас от таких ошибок, рекомендую установить linux(ubuntu) и компилятор gcc/g++ и писать в sublime, если хотите научиться программировать и не прикреплять код  картинкой.

Comment: именно функция `main` имеет льготу не вызывать `return`. по-умолчанию она возвращает ноль.

Comment: вы абсолютно правы, однако, для читаемости кода и конкретизации поведения, лично я всегда пишу return. Если что-то можно прописать конкретно, это нужно прописывать

Comment: @SpaceResearcher картинку я прикрепил, чтобы было видно ошибку